# Start multiple instances of the same Windows Service

Tags: windows, service

I have a Windows Service that creates a TCP Client, reads entries from a barcode scanner with fixed IP address in my network and performs various actions in a database.

The service is started by a simple .bat file :

```
@ECHO OFF
sc start myService IPAddress Port
PAUSE
```

Problem is, it's possible that several barcode scanner will be used at the same time.
When I try to start a .bat with another IP address, I have an error saying that the service is already running.

Is it possible to do without creating and installing another service with a slightly different name ?

Comment: only one instance of service can run

Comment: @RbMm Ok, so I have to create a different service and installer for each instance I want to run ?

Comment: if this is your code - you need design it to do functional in single instance